# How to log into network in linux?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, distributions, openwrt

I am using a custom version of OpenWRT linux that is used as a dev enviroment for a a graphic library. I am using it as a Virtualbox image. The distro contains a proxy module that needs to access the network and be assigned it's own IP. I set the network settings to "Internal Network" and now I am stumped on how to log into my network.

The distro is all command line, can anyone tell me how to access the network?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up the VM in virtualbox so that it has a a bridged adapter. See the official docs, or read here: http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html

Giving it a bridged adapter will allow it to be on the same network that your host machine is on, as this is what i think you mean when you say "it needs its own ip".